# Ionic/Cordova app doesn't receives push notification in the background

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

My Android app doesn't receive push notifications in the background and it should according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/).

> An Android application on an Android device doesn't need to be running
>   to receive messages. The system will wake up the Android application
>   via Intent broadcast when the message arrives, as long as the
>   application is set up with the proper broadcast receiver and
>   permissions.

Trying different notifications discovered that it does receives the push notifications while it is closed if and only if the notifications contains the attribute **"message"**, if not, it just discards it. (Push notifications are just JSON objects).

My notifications contain all kind of attributes including "alert", "id" and "title", but only "message" makes Android to wake up the app.

Example notification that **doesn't work**:

```
{ event: 'message',
  from: '947957531940',
  collapse_key: 'do_not_collapse',
  foreground: true,
  payload: 
   { alert: 'Mensaje de Prueba',
     title: 'Titulo Mensaje de Prueba' } }
```

Example notification that **works**:

```
{ event: 'message',
  from: '947957531940',
  message: 'Contenido del mensaje de prueba.',
  collapse_key: 'do_not_collapse',
  foreground: true,
  payload: 
   { alert: 'Mensaje de Prueba',
     title: 'Titulo Mensaje de Prueba',
     message: 'Contenido del mensaje de prueba.' } }
```

Is this an Android standard by design or am I doing something wrong in my app?

My app was developed using Ionic with Cordova.

PD: Excuse my english.

**EDIT:**

This is the Android push code inside the .run module in app.js, as [ng-cordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/) instructions specify:

```
if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()){

  var androidConfig = {
    "senderID": "94*************",
    "ecb": "window.casosPush"
  };

  try{
    var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
  } catch (ex){

  }

  // Llamada en caso de exito
  var successfn = function(result){
    //alert("Success: " + result);
  };

  // Llamada en caso de error
  var errorfn   = function(result){
    window.alert("Error: " + result);
  };

  // Llamada de casos de notificacion push
  window.casosPush = function(notification){
    switch (notification.event){
      case 'registered':
        if (notification.regid.length > 0){
          $rootScope.data.token = notification.regid;
          //alert('registration ID = ' + notification.regid);
        }
      break;

      case 'message':

        $rootScope.mensajes.unshift(notification.payload);
        $localstorage.setArray('mensajes', $rootScope.mensajes);
        alert(JSON.stringify(notification));
      break;

      case 'error':
        alert('GCM error = ' + notification.msg);
      break;

      default:
        alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
      break;
    }
  };
  try{

    // Llamada de registro con la plataforma GCM 
    pushNotification.register(successfn,errorfn,androidConfig);
  } catch(notification){

  }
}
```

Comment: whats your meaning "close"? "force close" in setting? If yes, then it will never get push later after doing that.

Comment: @TeeTracker no, not force closed, just not active, in background, not currently active in the screen. I know very well push notifications doesn'twork if the app is force closed.

Comment: Can you show me your code?

Comment: @cfprabhu is the standar code from ng-cordova example, I'll update the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After searching all questions in stackoverflow involving Cordova/Phonegap Push Plugin I found de source of the problem. Is written in the source code of the plugin, and it shouldn't.

The problem was that the plugin source code requires the push notification to have "message" field in order to trigger a notification while being on the background. It is especified in the **GCMIntentService.java** file.

```
if (extras.getString("message") != null && extras.getString("message").length() != 0) {
    createNotification(context, extras);
}
```

The most helpful posts are this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30095461/4275425) and this [issue](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/212) in the plugin repository. So, because I have no power over the push server action I can't have specified a "message" field in the push notifications, I had no alternative but to rewrite the source code.

So I rewrote te code like this:

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onMessage - context: " + context);

    // Extract the payload from the message
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null)
    {
        // if we are in the foreground, just surface the payload, else post it to the statusbar
        if (PushPlugin.isInForeground()) {
            extras.putBoolean("foreground", true);
            PushPlugin.sendExtras(extras);
        }
        else {
            extras.putBoolean("foreground", false);

            // Send a notification if there is a message
            //if (extras.getString("message") != null && extras.getString("message").length() != 0) {
            if (extras.getString("alert") != null && extras.getString("alert").length() != 0) {
                createNotification(context, extras);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That way the plugin triggers a local notification if it receives a push notifications with the field "alert" instead of "message".

Then, I changed the code for the local notification itself:

```
public void createNotification(Context context, Bundle extras)
{
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String appName = getAppName(this);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, PushHandlerActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("pushBundle", extras);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        int defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;

        if (extras.getString("defaults") != null) {
            try {
                defaults = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("defaults"));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setDefaults(defaults)
                .setSmallIcon(context.getApplicationInfo().icon)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                //.setContentTitle(extras.getString("title"))
                .setContentTitle(extras.getString("alert"))
                //.setTicker(extras.getString("title"))
                .setTicker(extras.getString("alert"))
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
    /*
        String message = extras.getString("message");
        if (message != null) {
            mBuilder.setContentText(message);
        } else {
            mBuilder.setContentText("<missing message content>");
        }
    */
    // Agregado mensaje predefinido
    mBuilder.setContentText("Haz clic para más información");

        String msgcnt = extras.getString("msgcnt");
        if (msgcnt != null) {
            mBuilder.setNumber(Integer.parseInt(msgcnt));
        }

        int notId = 0;

        try {
            notId = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("notId"));
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Number format exception - Error parsing Notification ID: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Number format exception - Error parsing Notification ID" + e.getMessage());
        }

        mNotificationManager.notify((String) appName, notId, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

Now the notification in the notification bar will show first the field "alert" instead of "title" and second a predefined message instead of the field "message" that doesn't exist in my push notifications.

Then I just recompile the code with:

```
ionic platform rm android

ionic platform add android

ionic run android
```

So kids, this is what happens when you write a plugin for everyone but you don't consider generic cases and you don't document well. That plugin is only useful for people with the field "message" and "title" in their push notifications.

I lost two days of my internship because of this, I took my time to write this so others won't have to.

Comment: You don't know how many days I've lost trying to get notifications to work in ionic...

Comment: Yes, I know @enlitement

Comment: Did you find a fix for this for iOS?

Comment: @enlitement I haven't had a chance to look at the iOS version but as I recall it didn't need the "message" attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You are right @David prieto.
The problem was that the plugin source code requires the push notification to have "message" field in order to trigger a notification while being on the background.

There is one way to put "message" field in push notification and its simple.
Payload array which has data of notification, which is send through an API. It should have an "message" field in it. So the push notification will automatically have a message field in it and it will get detected in background as well as foreground.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I solved by changing some lines of codes.
 I used **phonegap-plugin-push** plugin and changed this file.(for android platform only)

**plugin folder** : *phonegap-plugin-push/src/android/com/adobe/phonegap/push/FCMService.java*

**platform folder**: *android/src/com/adobe/phonegap/push/FCMService.java*

You need to change one of two files, which depends on you already added platform or not.

```
  // if we are in the foreground and forceShow is `false` only send data
  if (!forceShow && PushPlugin.isInForeground()) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "foreground");
    extras.putBoolean(FOREGROUND, true);
    extras.putBoolean(COLDSTART, false);
    PushPlugin.sendExtras(extras); 
  }
  // if we are in the foreground and forceShow is `true`, force show the notification 
  if the data has at least a message or title
  else if (forceShow && PushPlugin.isInForeground()) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "foreground force");
    extras.putBoolean(FOREGROUND, true);
    extras.putBoolean(COLDSTART, false);
    showNotificationIfPossible(applicationContext, extras);
  }
  // if we are not in the foreground always send notification if the data has at least a message or title
  else {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "background");
    extras.putBoolean(FOREGROUND, false);
    extras.putBoolean(COLDSTART, PushPlugin.isActive());
    showNotificationIfPossible(applicationContext, extras);
  }
```

> Here, PushPlugin.sendExtras() , this is the trigger for
>   localNotification and showNotificationIfPossible() is the trigger for
>   phone notification.

So I changed the code like this.

```
  // if we are in the foreground and forceShow is `false` only send data   
  if (!forceShow && PushPlugin.isInForeground()) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "foreground");
    extras.putBoolean(FOREGROUND, true);
    extras.putBoolean(COLDSTART, false);
    //PushPlugin.sendExtras(extras);  // commented   }   
  // if we are in the foreground and forceShow is `true`, force show the notification  if the data has at least a message or title   
  else if (forceShow && PushPlugin.isInForeground()) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "foreground force");
    extras.putBoolean(FOREGROUND, true);
    extras.putBoolean(COLDSTART, false);
    //showNotificationIfPossible(applicationContext, extras);// commented   }   
  // if we are not in the foreground always send notification if the data has at least a message or title   
  else {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "background");
    extras.putBoolean(FOREGROUND, false);
    extras.putBoolean(COLDSTART, PushPlugin.isActive());
    //showNotificationIfPossible(applicationContext, extras); // commented   
 }   
 PushPlugin.sendExtras(extras); //added
```

So I can get the notification and process it using localNotification plugin as I want.
Hope this will help you.