# Ionic Push Notifications - Use data after clicking notification

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-messaging, ionic2, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use Ionic push notifications. This is my current app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen } from 'ionic-native';
import {
  Push,
  PushToken
} from '@ionic/cloud-angular';

import { Page1 } from '../pages/page1/page1';
import { Page2 } from '../pages/page2/page2';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage: any = Page1;

  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

  constructor(
    public platform: Platform,
    public push: Push
  ) {
    this.setupPushNotifications();
    this.initializeApp();

    // used for an example of ngFor and navigation
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Page One', component: Page1 },
      { title: 'Page Two', component: Page2 }
    ];

  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }

  setupPushNotifications() {

    this.push.register().then((t: PushToken) => {
      return this.push.saveToken(t);
    }).then((t: PushToken) => {
      console.log('Token saved:', t.token);
    });

    this.push.rx.notification()
      .subscribe((msg) => {

        console.log(msg);

        alert(msg.title + ': ' + msg.text);
      });

  }

}
```

I am then using the following Node.js app to send push messages:

```
var request = require('request');

function sendMessageToUser(deviceId, message) {
  request({
    url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type' :' application/json',
      'Authorization': 'key=AI....'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(
      {
        "to" : deviceId,
        "notification": {
          "title": "Push Notification",
          "body": message,
          "sound": ""
        },
        "data": {
          "test": "test 1"
        }
      }
    )
  }, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error, response, body);
    }
    else if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
      console.error('HTTP Error: '+response.statusCode+' - '+response.statusMessage+'\n'+body);
    }
    else {
      console.log('Done!')
    }
  });
}

sendMessageToUser(
  "eu....",
  'Test'
);
```

If the app is open and I send a push notification, the `console.log()` and the `alert()` execute OK. However when the app is in the background or the phone is locked, I get a notification as expected, but then when I click on this the app opens without executing either the `console.log()` or the `alert()` function.

Could someone please tell me how I can achieve this?

I have tried sending push notifications from Ionic.io's cloud system instead, and it works fine when using that so perhaps I am missing an option in my node app?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Based from this [thread](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/257), push plugin expects that the message will contain at least one field with Key as "message" and maybe you sending as "Message" so it was not going in the case. You can also check on this [related SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31212507/ionic-cordova-app-doesnt-receives-push-notification-in-the-background). It stated that the plugin source code requires the push notification to have `message` field in order to trigger a notification while being on the background.

Comment: I tried adding a 'message' or 'Message' field but it still didn't help unfortunately. I think I will stick to the Ionic.io push system for now because I won't need 10,000 notifications a month anyway.